# ¿Cómo insertar el último registro de una tabla en PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que utiliza PostgreSQL en el cual tengo tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios (

id_usuario  BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
nombre      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
contrasena  varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario));
```

```
CREATE TABLE Estudiantes (

boleta     varchar(10) NOT NULL,
nombre     varchar(255) NOT NULL,
apellido   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
correo     varchar(255) NOT NULL,
id_usuario    int8 NOT NULL,



CONSTRAINT FK_usuarios FOREIGN KEY(id_usuario) REFERENCES Usuarios(id_usuario)

  PRIMARY KEY (boleta));
CONSTRAINT FK_employee_department FOREIGN KEY(dept_id)
        REFERENCES department(dept_id)
```

Lo que me gustaría lograr es insertar en la tabla **Estudiantes** el último ID (como una FK) de la tabla **Usuarios**, para que cada vez que se inserte un nuevo registro en la tabla Usuarios el valor también se agregue de forma simultanea en la tabla de Estudiantes.

En MySQL suelo hacerlo de esta manera, pero no sé como se podría implementar algo similar en Postgres:

```
INSERT INTO Usuarios(nombre, contrasena) VALUES ('juan', '12345); 
SET @lastUsuario = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO Estudiantes (boleta,nombre,apellido,correo,id_usuario) VALUES ('20015','Juan','Perez', @lastUsuario);
```

Cabe mencionar que no estoy seguro que la forma en la que lo hago en MySQL sea la más adecuada, así que también acepto sugerencias de como mejorar.

Comment: El primer problema que yo veo, es..... y ¿porqué la sentencia de inserción va a tener una sola fila? Y si values trae varias o directamente el insert into es desde una select....Lo que planteas no soluciona este escenario. Si las inserciones las haces sólo desde un sitio y de una manera, puede ser, pero sino, quizá debieras de buscar un trigger para la inserción. O quizá utilizar [returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249910/output-inserted-id-equivalent-in-postgres) En resumidas cuentas, busca la solución para múltiples inserciones simultaneas

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que analices la opción de utilizar la claúsula [`RETURNING` de PostgreSQL en las sentencias `INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html), combinado con algun `WITH` puedes hacer tu magia, por ejemplo:

```sql
 WITH el_insert as (
INSERT INTO Usuarios(nombre,contrasena) VALUES ('juan', '12345')  RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO Estudiantes select '20015','Juan','Perez','a@correo.com', el_insert.id_usuario from el_insert;
```